# Keyboard shortcuts in Outlook not working as they should

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

In my instance of Outlook, the letter "k" is underlined in the "Mark as read" context menu item. However, according to [this document](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/keyboardshortcuts.htm), the shortcut to mark an email as read is Control+Enter.

After trying both of these options, I've found that Control+Enter works, while Control-K does not work. Why is this the case? Coming from a Macintosh background, can someone explain to me if I am reading the Windows "shotcut underlinings" wrong, and if so, how they are to be read?

EDIT: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 with Outlook 2013.

Comment: What is your Windows version and Outlook version (and language, as MS loves to change keyboard shortcuts in localized versions, Word being a famous example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this instance, those underlined keys are "shortcuts" only when you have that right click/context menu open.

For example, you right click on an emails and see the *K* in *Mark as Read* underlined, hit <kbd>K</kbd> and that option is highlighted, *hitting enter will trigger the action (only required for some commands, see edit).*

You could speed this up into a keyboard only sequence by hitting <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (if your keyboard happens to have the menu key... mine is a function key)

Like a lot of things in Windows, it's just another way of doing the same action. This way is (arguably) faster than using the mouse and "easily" discoverable, but using the "real" shortcut, if you know it, is even faster.

---

Edit: In fact only some options require that you to hit enter. Marking Unread or Read does require enter, but replying does not.

Comment: That these shortcuts faster than using the mouse is very arguable. I.e., my keyboard does not have the menu key, and therefore one would have to right click the item then click the `k` item on the keyboard. Also, the fact that the "context-menu keyboard shortcut" and the "normal keyboard shortcut" use different key combinations also makes learning the shortcuts difficult. Yet another series of factors as to why Microsoft suck at design.